# Regex to fetch all matching values from xml node

Tags: java, regex

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240617/regex-to-fetch-xml-node-string-value) it gives me just 1st match. I want to get all the matching into a string or a string array

This is my part of output from which I need to extract all `Category`'s

```
<Trace Enabled="false">
        <ActiveCategories>
            <Category>ENVIRONMENT</Category>
            <Category>EXEC</Category>
            <Category>EXTERNALS</Category>
            <Category>FILESYSTEM</Category>
            <Category>INPUT_DOC</Category>
            <Category>INTERFACES</Category>
            <Category>NETWORKING</Category>
            <Category>OUTPUT_DOC</Category>
            <Category>PREPROCESSOR_INPUT</Category>
            <Category>REQUEST</Category>
            <Category>SYSTEMRESOURCES</Category>
            <Category>VIEWIO</Category>
            <Category>ALL</Category>
        </ActiveCategories>
        <SeverityLevel>ERROR</SeverityLevel>
        <MessageInfo>
            <ProcessAndThreadIds>true</ProcessAndThreadIds>
            <TimeStamp>true</TimeStamp>
        </MessageInfo>
        <TraceFile>
            <FileName>CMDS_log.txt</FileName>
            <MaxFileSize>1000000</MaxFileSize>
            <RecyclingMethod>Restart</RecyclingMethod>
        </TraceFile>
    </Trace>
```

right now through the below code I am only able to fetch `ENVIRONMENT`, I need to fetch all of the `Category`'s value

```
def regexFinder(String myInput,String myRegex)
{
String ResultString
Pattern regex
Matcher regexMatcher

regex = Pattern.compile(myRegex, Pattern.DOTALL);
regexMatcher = regex.matcher(myInput);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
}
}

tempResultString=regexFinder(ResultString,"(?<=<Category>)(?:(?!</Category>).)*")
    csm.cmengine_category(tempResultString)
    {           "${rs}"     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `.find()` repeatedly to iterate over all results:

```
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(myInput);
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So does it come into a String array or a String?

Comment: Well, `regexMatcher.group()` is a string. I've changed my sample to put the results into an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3):

### Don't use regex to parse XML, use a parser.

See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Of course you're right in principle. But in this simple case (machine-generated, well-formed XML without comments or quoted strings) I think you can get away with regexes if you're aware that it's a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Machine generated usually meaning that a developper created the program that generate it, I'm as worried about it's validity as if it was manually written! More seriously, using the right tool to the right task is important. Regex just aren't suited to parse XML ontheir own.